# With aurelia validation, is there a way to require one OR another form field? (see commented code)?

Tags: aurelia

With aurelia validation, is there a way to require one OR another form field? (see commented code)?..or guidance on assigning rules to variables as the documentation wasn't very in depth (Junior Dev Here). I was originally trying to create a custom rule to handle it but was having trouble getting it to work properly.  The custom rule could then change the rule assigned to the var depending on field input.

```
const initialRules = ValidationRules
        .ensure('newContactFirstName').required()
        .ensure('newContactLastName').required()

        // if phone number not filled out require email
        .ensure('newContactEmail').required().then().email()

        //if email not filled out rquire phone number
        .ensure('newContactAreaCode').required().then().satisfiesRule('isNumber').then().minLength(3).then().maxLength(3)
        .ensure('newContactPrefix').required().then().satisfiesRule('isNumber').then().minLength(3).then().maxLength(3)
        .ensure('newContactSuffix').required().then().satisfiesRule('isNumber').then().minLength(4).then().maxLength(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use custom rules. Try something like this:

```
ValidationRules.ensure("newContactEmail").satisfies((email, myObject) => {
        if (email)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return myObject.newContactAreaCode != ""
                && myObject.newContactPrefix != ""
                && myObject.newContactSuffix != ""
        }
    })
    .on(myObject)
```

Basically, If the email has a value, the validation passes, else check to make sure the phone number fields have values.

I'd also advise you to take a look [here](http://www.sobell.net/aurelia-validation-part-3-custom-rules-and-validations/).